# notepad ++ remove number in {{0,0},{123,123}}

Tags: notepad++

I had a problem to remove some random numbers in notepad ++
and this is a difficult thing for me
can you help me for remove some number
like here

I want to delete `{{0,0}`

Before

```
{{0,0},{123,123}}
```

after

```
{123,123}
```

Comment: Please, give an example. Some lines before and after.

Comment: Before <string>{{0,0},{123,123}}</string>                                                                    After    <string>{123,123}}</string>

Comment: Edit your question and add more examples. Do you want to remove only `{{0,0}`? In this case the curly brackets are not balanced, is it OK?

Comment: yes i want to delete {{0,0}

Comment: Why does replacing `{{0,0}`  or `{0,0}` with nothing  not work?

Comment: {0,0} hmmm
please help

Comment: Use Search -> Replace menu, search for `{0,0}` replace with ``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `\{\{0,0\},(\{123,123\})\}`
Replace with: `$1`

To be more generalist:

Find what: `\{\{\d+,\d+\},(\{\d+,\d+\})\}`
Replace with: `$1`